# Saving Post redirects to 404 page when php $_GET variable in post body

Tags: php, posts, 404-error, bug

I am having a very annoying issue where certain posts redirect to 404 page when trying to save or publish a post. It only happens to a few posts and did not happen prior to the last few WP updates. I tried disabling all plugins and using different themes with no change. I also tried creating a new post on a different WordPress installation again with no change.

In one post I narrowed it down to one line that if taken out solves the issue, though there is no such line in another post that gives 404 error:

```
$_GET["ip"];
```

or even:

```
$_GET
```

But this causes no issues:

```
$_GE
```

I realise this is a PHP global variable but I don't see why it should cause an issue in a post body as WP should not be interpreting it as code. The PHP variable is part of the code I am displaying within pre tags. Another post that now redirects to 404 page saved just fine when it was first written and so did the post with the GET variable. This means something must have changed in WP.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Post your code please. It is impossible to tell what your are doing.

Comment: Like I said it's not the code it's that the post redirects to 404 page when the line above is present anywhere in the post body. It is not supposed to be interpreted as code but rather as text.

Comment: And it will be interpreted as text because WordPress doesn't process PHP in the post body... unless you or a plugin or a theme is messing with the system. I don't know which but I am 99% sure it isn't Core. Have you disabled your plugins and switched to a bundled theme like Twenty Fifteen?

Comment: I just tried with another WP install with same results. All plugins were disabled. Theme was TwentyThirteen and I also tried TwentyTwelve. I created new post with  only '$_GET["ip"];' in the body and tried saving it as a draft. Still 404. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I tried the exact same thing with current WP 4.2.3, it does get weirdly - although it is correct, because it is consider as text - "corrected" like this »$_GET[„IP“]« though, but I cannot confirm it creating a 404 error.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does get weirdly - although it is correct, because it is consider as text - "corrected"?

Comment: See the quotes, I clicked on this again by chance, if you want notify a person use `@username` in your comment, people only automatically get notified when it is their question or answer.

Comment: @ialocin Didn't know that, thanks. For me even with those quotes I still get 404, really strange stuff... "$_GET" in any format gets me 404 error when saving...

Comment: Checked with latest WP, working fine with me, try clear your browser's cache if you still get such errors after disabling the plugins.

Comment: @RaviKumar Please read the question and comments, I already said I tried disabling ALL plugins. I also tried using IE which I never normally use so it's not cache.

Comment: **Calm down buddy!!!** We are trying to solve the problem here! always go through few checklists/suggestions. If you still not found the solution try to install new version of WP local/live scenario and check whether you are getting same error or not. If you found same error please create a ticket for this. PS: also provide which version you are currently working on in your questions.

Comment: @RaviKumar Emmm, I think I was being perfectly calm reminding you to not to ask me to do things I already have already said I tried, bold text and triple exclamation is not very calm though :) I was just thinking I should try installing WP on my local server, will get back when I tried this.

Comment: With fresh WP 4.2.3 install on a local server it works fine. Any way something on the server side could be causing this? Anything else to look into?

Comment: You maybe - or maybe not - misunderstood me, those quotes are the correction that WordPress does if it assumes the string is text not code. Anyway, some server configuration problem would have been me next guess too, but nothing comes immediately to my mind, so I'm not of real further help.

Comment: @RaviKumar I know you are trying to help, but you should take your own advice here, to not being borderline rude, so be cool, calm and collected - thanks.

Comment: @ialocin Will try to install WP on the remote server and see if it works there. Can't imagine why it could affect WP unless there is a bug in WP that only shows up with specific server config. I mean WP should not be interpreting any text as php within a post no matter what.

Comment: You are right, but if it actually is the WordPress installation, then it is somehow corrupted - hacked or whatever -, which means you should replace all core code to be sure it isn't something like this.

Comment: @ialocin The thing is that it's 2 different installation that display the same issue. I even tried reinstalling WP with no effect. The only other thing I can think of is that a plugin or theme is causing the issue even when deactivated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26296/discussion-between-ialocin-and-dominicm).